# C#.NET - Compress Encrypted Files to 7z Format

Tags: c#, .net, 7zip

I need to compress folder with files in `.7z` format.

I use SevenZip for it with class `SevenZipCompressor.cs`.
There are a method `CompressFilesEncrypted()`. How to compress folder with files?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: yes, but there are no method for folder to encrypt with password(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use some thing like http://code.google.com/p/tar-cs/ to create a tar file then compress the tar file!

Comment: What does this have to do with encryption ?

Comment: Maybe somebody has experience?

Comment: I found what I need:

SevenZipCompressor obj = new SevenZipCompressor(); obj.CompressDirectory(@"C:\source\host_update", @"C:\source\host_update\123.7z", zipkey);

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to compress an encrypted file (at least with any decent cipher).

You need to compress, then encrypt to get the 'desired' result.

Comment: how to kompress file? I use: SevenZipCompressor hostfile7 = new SevenZipCompressor(); webfile7.CompressDirectory(@"C:\source\host_update\", "host_update"); but it doesn't work(

Comment: I found what I need: SevenZipCompressor obj = new SevenZipCompressor(); obj.CompressDirectory(@"C:\source\host_update", @"C:\source\host_update\123.7z", zipkey);